# Storing OpenStreetMap data in Neo4j - Need advice on defined structure

Tags: neo4j, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am currently working on a project that involves integrating OpenStreetMap (OSM) data into a Neo4j database. I'm wondering if there is a recommended or defined structure for storing OSM data in Neo4j. I want to ensure that the data is organized efficiently and can be easily queried for spatial analysis and retrieve useful information.

At the moment, I'm only working with the library OSMX in Python to retrive information from OpenStreetmap, but the idea is to put spatial information retrived with Python in a Neo4j Database.

I've done some research, but I couldn't find a comprehensive guide or recommendation for structuring OSM data in Neo4j. Any guidance or insights from experienced Neo4j users who have worked with OSM data would be immensely helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like this may work: OSMnx to create graph, then ox.graph_to_gdfs to convert graph to node/edge GeoPandas GeoDataFrames, then save GeoDataFrames to CSV, then import CSV into Neo4j https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/data-import/csv-import/